# Check whether a value exists in a JSON object using Java

Tags: java, json

I'm very new to Java and trying to find and check whether a particular value exists in JSON object. Here is my code,

```
String strUsers = representation.getText();     
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strUsers);

    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObj.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        String val = null;
        try {
             JSONObject value = jsonObj.getJSONObject(key);

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Further I'm not able to understand how to check. Can any one guide me in achieving my goal?

Answer (score 5):

You should use the method `has`.

```
if(jsonObject.has("your_key")) {
    // get the value and do something with it
}
```

In your `try-catch` block, before getting the value check if the key actually exists.

```
if (jsonObject.has(key)) {
    // then get the value
    JSONObject value = jsonObj.getJSONObject(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Can you give me a very basic example?